# How to search a collapsed JSON document

Tags: solr

I have condensed by json document down into a few fields: Content, Title and id

id is simple a unique Id, title is the page title eg "A page title" and content is everything else so in this context elements that make up a web page so: Image alt text, text on the page etc etc but no HTML just the raw content. I want to be able to perform a search across this content block so say it looks like this

"an image alt text some text from the page" if i search for "from the page" I'd expect a result. However I'm not getting any. My field type for content is set to include the following filters

```
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
```

However when I query my index even with single words I get no results:
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1_shard2_replica1/select?q=*page*&wt=json&indent=true

Being new to Solr and thrown rather in the deep end I am struggling!

Answer (score 0):

The first question is whether this indexed at all. Check what you see in the [Admin UI's Schema Browser screen](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Browser+Screen) when you load tokens for those fields. If you don't see your Title and Content fields, you need to look at the indexing.

If the content is there, the question is how you search it. You need to either specify default field (**df** parameter) for default search type or something like field list (**fl** parameter) with eDisMax. You are not doing it explicitly in your query, so this must be set in the solrconfig.xml for the /select handler. Check what you have there.

Most likely it searches **text** field. For this to work, there needs to be a copyField from your **Content** and **Title** field into the **text** field, either individually or as a glob (**srcField="*")**. Note that since you search text field, the analysis chain applied is for that field, not for whatever field you copied the content from. Again, load the tokens for **text** field in the Admin UI to see what it contains.

Alternatively, try adding **df=Content** to your query above and see if you get some results. That would also mean that whatever the default field is, it is not populated or not populated properly.